# How to enable 'Vector Tile API' in google cloud platform console?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am setting up Google Maps Platform gaming solution in Unity using my project api key and a new lat-long value but its not creating any model in scene. It works perfect when I use lat-long given by example scene with SDK.

I have created api key in google cloud platform console. I am unable to find 'Vector Tile API' to enable in console(If that is the issue).

According to docs when we use our own api key and lat-long other then example one, it should generate new model data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Maps Unity SDK FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/gaming/support/faq#whichapi) states that it uses the Vector Tile API  and Playable Locations API, both of which are not listed as part of [Google Maps Core Services](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/maps-services/).

I cannot fin specific for these APIs in their documentation, although for the [Google Maps Tile API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/tile/) they state:

> If you have not yet purchased access to the API, please [contact Sales](https://developers.google.com/maps/contact-sales/).

Hence I presume something similar goes for the Vector Tile and Playable Locations API.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update, the [Google Maps Platform Gaming Solution is available to the public now](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/maps-platform/google-maps-platform-gaming-services-now-available-everyone).

You can enable the Vector Tile API or what is now called the [Semantic Tile API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/vectortile.googleapis.com) through the Cloud Console Library.

Note that you will need a Billing Account to be able to get started with the GMP Gaming Services (e.g. Semantic Tile API and Playability Locations API)

Here's their [getting started doc.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/gaming/get_started_gaming) You'll see where to enable the APIs and how to create API keys to use with the Maps SDK for Unity.